# 'Bad Credentials' error in traditional Login form

Tags: php, security, symfony, doctrine

I am new in symfony and trying to develop Login application with help of [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).But 
I got error on submit event as below

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException' with message 'Bad credentials' in D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:90 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(3366): session_start() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(3444): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(3190): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->getBag('attributes') #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener.php(76): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->get('_security_secur...') #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(4644): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #5 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)) #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php(392): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)) #7 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #8 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(2903): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #9 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(2836): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #10 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\cache\dev\classes.php(3000): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #11 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php(139): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #12 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2900): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #13 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2883): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #14 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\bootstrap.php.cache(3022): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #15 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2303): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #16 D:\xampp\htdocs\LoginProject\web\app_dev.php(28): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #17 {main}
```

please check my code below

**Security.yml**

```
   secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: login_login_homepage

        logout:
            path:   login_login_logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session:   true

        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
     - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
     - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: /user, roles: ROLE_USER }
     - { path: /.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**Routing.yml**

```
login_login_homepage:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:login }

check_login:
    pattern: /login_check
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){
         $session = $request->getSession();

       if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
           $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
           );
       }else{
           $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
           $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
       }


       $login = $this->check_loginAction($request->get('username'),$request->get('password'));
       if($login){
           return $this->render(
                'LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig',
                array(
                    'last_username'=>$session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME)
                )
        );
       }else{
        return $this->render(
                'LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig',
                array(
                    'last_username'=>'Error',
                    'error'=>$error,
                )
        );
      }
    }

    public function check_loginAction($username,$password){

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $respondary = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Login');

            $login = $respondary->findOneBy(array('user' => $username, 'pass' => $password));
            if($login){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
                //$this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig', array('error' => 'Login Failed'));
            }

    }
```

Please help me out it.

Answer (score 2):

You entered wrong username or password. Check your **username** and **password** in `security.yml`:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

Comment: Thanx @Victor but i want to check existing username in mysql table.then how can i do it?

Comment: If you want to use DB for store users, read the [How to load Security Users from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider). There is example with `loadUserByUsername` method of `UserRepository` for loading user from  DB by username

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement `check_loginAction`. `Symfony2` will take care of it.

So, in the controller, the`loginAction` is simply as:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig', array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

The most important thing is to make sure that you set the right provider, it should point to a `User` class that you have implemented. For example, let's say you have the `User` class inside your LoginLoginBundle located in the `Acme\Bundle`. So, the provider should be set as following:

```
providers:
        main:
          entity: { class: Acme\Bundle\LoginLoginBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

Finally, you should make sure that the `role_hierarchy` is set to match the Role's name in your `Role` class:

```
role_hierarchy:
        YourRoleName1: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPERADMIN]
        YourRoleName2: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
        YourRoleName3: ROLE_USER
        YourRoleName4: ROLE_USER
```